# How to write SSRS expression with OR condition involving a field and a parameter?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, filtering, ssrs-expression

I have a set of tablix results that im trying to filter based on OR condition but im having difficulty combining the two into one custom expression. [IsSafetyObservation] is just a boolean field and [Department] needs to be part of the multi-selected parameter values of [@Department]. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like as two separate filters but this is doing AND condition. When I tried to write custom expression I'm not using the write syntax because I get a red line when I try to reference the @Department parameter

[tablix filter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp951.png)
[custom expression attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLxQ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to combine your expressions into one as you tried but instead of using IN, you should use **InStr**. InStr searches for a string inside another string and returns the position or 0 if not found.

First you would need to combine your parameters into a string using JOIN.

```
JOIN(Parameters!Department.Value, ",")
```

This will combine your parameters into a single string that you can now search for the Department field in the Department parameter.

```
InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Department.Value, ","), Fields!Department.Value) > 0
```

Also, SSRS doesn't always work well with Booleans (ugh) - so an expression of `= (1 = 1)` may work in some places for a Boolean result but not others so it's best to specify:

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Department.Value, ","), Fields!Department.Value) > 0 
    OR Fields!IsSafetyObservation.Value = False, 
        True,
        False)
```

Comment: Wow cool, thanks so much. I'll definitely play around with this, in the meantime we just decided to handle the parameter in the stored proc itself so we could easily handle the filters/conditions